# Laravel Scheduler and Cron

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, cron, laravel-artisan

I'm writing a CMS with the Laravel as a backend and Vue.js as a frontend. So far, I had no problems with the application, however, when I tried to create Scheduler to manage tasks from the frontend, I'm not able to run these tasks with provided Laravel cron task:
`* * * * * php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`
Well, actually I can, if I redirect the output of the CRON to the **file** and not **/dev/null**, Laravel is telling me that the job is executed successfully, however, nothing is happening.

To test out that created Scheduler class is able to call the jobs at an assigned times, I've written small node.js notification application, which simply sends the system notification.

In case if I'm calling the `php artisan schedule:run` myself, I have no problem with receiving this notification, and yet again, I have a new entry in the log file telling me that job executed successfully.
But when CRON executes the same artisan command, the only thing I get is entry in the log file but no notification.

I'm running Apache server under the same user which has this cron entry and the node.js script is placed under in the home path of this same user. So from here I've no idea why this might happen.

**P.S.** This is the interface which basically shows how the crontab is edited and what I'm adding to it to make this thing work (but for some reason it is just spitting messages to log without actually doing anything):

[image]

And this is how the task looks like:

[image]

Comment: Don't dump the output to /dev/null so you can see what it says..

Comment: @Devon As i've already stated in the question, i tried that

Comment: There really isn't enough vital details in your question.  My guess is your Laravel command isn't written to actually check for errors when the shell command runs but you haven't posted any relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides an easy way for [task scheduling](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-cron-job-scheduling). Laravel’s ‘Command Scheduler’ allows you to easily define the schedule of the commands within Laravel itself. When using the scheduler, only one Cron entry is needed on the server.

Comment: My guess is that you haven't read the question. i'm already using build-in scheduler